# Treatment of Arrays in Go

Tags: arrays, go

Having read the following at http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#arrays...

> - Arrays are values. Assigning one array to another copies all the
>     elements.
> - In particular, if you pass an array to a function, it will receive a copy
>     of the array, not a pointer to it.

... I expect in the following code that `arr2` to be distinct from `arr`, and `main()`'s `arr` to be distinct from `shuffle()`'s `arr`. Can someone please explain why the following code shuffles `arr2`? I know Go is still a young language; perhaps the treatment of arrays has changed?

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "rand"
        "time"
)

func shuffle(arr []int) {
        rand.Seed(time.Nanoseconds())
        for i := len(arr) - 1; i > 0; i-- {
                j := rand.Intn(i)
                arr[i], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[i]
        }
}

func main() {
        arr := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
        arr2 := arr
        shuffle(arr)
        for _, i := range arr2 {
                fmt.Printf("%d ", i)
        }
}
```

Comment: Note: your `shuffle()` function should use `j := rand.Intn(i + 1)` else you exclude the probability of an element to remain in place, thus for example shuffleing `{1, 2}` would always result in `{2, 1}` and never in the other possible `{1, 2}` outcome.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think your problem is that you're confusing arrays and slices.

Arrays are fixed-length lists of values. You're actually not using any arrays in your example. Arrays can be declared a few ways:

```
arr1 := [3]int{1, 2, 3}   // an array of 3 integers, 1-3
arr2 := [...]int{1, 2, 3} // same as the previous line, but we're letting
                          // the compiler figure out the size of the array
var arr3 [3]int           // a zeroed out array of 3 integers
```

You're using slices. A slice is a reference to an underlying array. There are a few ways to allocate new slices:

```
slice1 := []int{1, 2, 3}    // a slice of length 3 containing the integers 1-3
slice2 := make([]int, 3)    // a slice of length 3 containing three zero-value integers
slice3 := make([]int, 3, 5) // a slice of length 3, capacity 5 that's all zeroed out
```

Any other slice assignments are just duplicating a reference to an array.

Now that we've established that, the line

```
arr := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

creates a slice referencing an anonymous underlying array that contains the numbers 1-5.

```
arr2 := arr
```

duplicates that reference -- it does *not* copy the underlying array. So there's one underlying array and two references to it. That's why the contents of arr2 change when you modify the contents of arr. They're referencing the same array.