# shuffle array in Go

Tags: arrays, go

I tried to translate the following Python code to Go

```
import random

list = [i for i in range(1, 25)]
random.shuffle(list)
print(list)
```

but found my Go version lengthy and awkward because there is no shuffle function and I had to implement interfaces and convert types.

What would be an idiomatic Go version of my code?

Comment: This question has a shuffle() implementation: [Treatment of Arrays in Go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221698/treatment-of-arrays-in-go).

Answer (score 106, accepted):

As your list is just the integers from 1 to 25, you can use [Perm](http://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#Rand.Perm) :

```
list := rand.Perm(25)
for i, _ := range list {
    list[i]++
}
```

Note that using a permutation given by `rand.Perm` is an effective way to shuffle any array.

```
dest := make([]int, len(src))
perm := rand.Perm(len(src))
for i, v := range perm {
    dest[v] = src[i]
}
```

Comment: I'm unsure if the Perm method has changed since this answer, but it returns "a pseudo-random permutation of the integers [0,n)". In this scenario, the outcome would be a permutation of 0 to 24.

Comment: @JayJay that's why the numbers are incremented (another solution would have been to just change 0 to 25).

Comment: Keep scrolling down, this is now supported out the box in 1.10: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46185753/474189

Answer (score 122):

[dystroy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12264918/510) is perfectly reasonable, but it's also possible to shuffle without allocating any additional slices.

```
for i := range slice {
    j := rand.Intn(i + 1)
    slice[i], slice[j] = slice[j], slice[i]
}
```

See [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) for more details on the algorithm. `rand.Perm` actually uses this algorithm internally as well.

Comment: I take it this is the "inside-out" version in the article, and you elide the `i!=j` check?

Comment: Looking at the Wikipedia page, this seems to be the "modern algorithm" (first variant).  The "inside-out" version seems to store the result in a new array, rather than doing the shuffle in place.

Comment: Caution: no, this isn't either "inside-out" or "modern". I advise against this suggestion. The "inside-out" algorithm works with the copy of the array/slice, i.e. operates two arrays/slices: `source` and `a` (shuffled). Here we have just one and it claims to operate in-place. It is also not "modern" either because "modern" should iterate from the end of the slice towards the beginning (excluding the very first element). Here it iterates from the first element till the end (including both). Either iteration direction or the way `j` is generated should change.

Answer (score 78):

Since 1.10 Go includes an official [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) function.

Documentation: [`pkg/math/rand/#Shuffle`](https://tip.golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#Shuffle)

> ### math/rand: add Shuffle
>
> Shuffle uses the Fisher-Yates algorithm.
>
> Since this is new API, it affords us the opportunity
> to use a much faster `Int31n` implementation that mostly avoids division.
>
> As a result, `BenchmarkPerm30ViaShuffle` is
> about 30% faster than `BenchmarkPerm30`,
> despite requiring a separate initialization loop
> and using function calls to swap elements.

See also the original [CL 51891](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/51891)

First, as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12264789/shuffle-array-in-go/46185753?noredirect=1#comment105168476_46185753) by [shelll](https://stackoverflow.com/users/671580/shelll):

> Do not forget to seed the random, or you will always get the same order.
> For example `rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())`

Example:

```
words := strings.Fields("ink runs from the corners of my mouth")
rand.Shuffle(len(words), func(i, j int) {
    words[i], words[j] = words[j], words[i]
})
fmt.Println(words)
```

Comment: @Deleplace Thank you. I have included this link in the answer.

Comment: Do not forget to seed the random, or you will always get the same order. For example `rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())`.

Comment: @shelll Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 10):

[Answer by Evan Shaw](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12267471/2775683) has a minor bug. If we iterate through the slice from lowest index to highest, to get a uniformly (pseudo) random shuffle, according to the [same article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm), we must choose a random integer from interval `[i,n)` *as opposed to `[0,n+1)`*.

That implementation will do what you need for larger inputs, but for smaller slices, it will perform a non-uniform shuffle.

To utilize `rand.Intn()`, we can do:

```
    for i := len(slice) - 1; i > 0; i-- {
        j := rand.Intn(i + 1)
        slice[i], slice[j] = slice[j], slice[i]
    }
```

following the same algorithm from Wikipedia article.

Comment: If an answer has a bug then edit the wrong answer, instead of writing yet another answer.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can also use the following function:

```
func main() {
   slice := []int{10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20}
   Shuffle(slice)
   fmt.Println(slice)
}

func Shuffle(slice []int) {
   r := rand.New(rand.NewSource(time.Now().Unix()))
   for n := len(slice); n > 0; n-- {
      randIndex := r.Intn(n)
      slice[n-1], slice[randIndex] = slice[randIndex], slice[n-1]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When using the `math/rand` package, do not forget to set a source

```
// Random numbers are generated by a Source. Top-level functions, such as
// Float64 and Int, use a default shared Source that produces a deterministic
// sequence of values each time a program is run. Use the Seed function to
// initialize the default Source if different behavior is required for each run.
```

So I wrote a `Shuffle` function that takes this into consideration:

```
import (
    "math/rand"
)

func Shuffle(array []interface{}, source rand.Source) {
    random := rand.New(source)
    for i := len(array) - 1; i > 0; i-- {
        j := random.Intn(i + 1)
        array[i], array[j] = array[j], array[i]
    }
}
```

And to use it:

```
source := rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano())
array := []interface{}{"a", "b", "c"}

Shuffle(array, source) // [c b a]
```

If you would like to use it, you can find it here https://github.com/shomali11/util

Answer (score 1):

[Raed's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44380373/7582250) is very inflexible because of `[]interface{}` as input. Here is more convenient version for **go>=1.8**:

```
func Shuffle(slice interface{}) {
    rv := reflect.ValueOf(slice)
    swap := reflect.Swapper(slice)
    length := rv.Len()
    for i := length - 1; i > 0; i-- {
            j := rand.Intn(i + 1)
            swap(i, j)
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano()) // do it once during app initialization
    s := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    Shuffle(s)
    fmt.Println(s) // Example output: [4 3 2 1 5]
```

And also, don't forget that [a little copying is better than a little dependency](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PAAkCSZUG1c&t=9m28s)